how to iterate through django-friendship provided template tag
I am using Django 5.1 and django-friendship library. django-friendship provides some built in template tags that work but not when I try and iterate over them. so {% friends request.user %} returns a list of friends by username. But I cant seem to get any of the template tags work work when I iterate through them.
{% if request.user != profile.user %}

    {% if profile.user in friends_list %}
        <p>You are friends with {{ profile.user.username }}.</p>
        <a href="{% url 'remove_friend' to_user_id=profile.user.id %}">Remove Friend</a>
    {% else %}
        {% for friend_request in friend_requests %}
            {% if friend_request.from_user == profile.user %}
                <p>{{ profile.user.username }} has sent you a friend request. Check your <a href="{% url 'view_friend_requests' %}">friend requests</a>.</p>
            {% elif friend_request.to_user == profile.user %}
                <p>You have already sent a friend request to {{ profile.user.username }}.</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% empty %}
            <a href="{% url 'send_friend_request' to_user_id=profile.user.id %}">Send Friend Request</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% else %}  {# This is the current user's own profile #}
    <h3>Your Friends</h3>
    {% if friends_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for friend in friends_list %}
                <li>{{ friend }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>You have no friends yet.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

Here is a full last of tag loader and tags.
{% load friendshiptags %}

{% friends request.user %}
{% followers request.user %}
{% following request.user %}
{% friend_requests request.user %}
{% friend_request_count request.user %}

